# WebDriver crashes on IE

Tags: python, internet-explorer, selenium

Suddenly my `Python` scripts on `Selenium` stop to launch because of following code and error:

```
from selenium import webdriver
dr = webdriver.Ie()*
```

*Actually new browser session opens on `webdriver`'s default page but `webdriver` stop to respond so no other commands could be executed

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python34\site-packages\sele
>   nium\webdriver\ie\webdriver.py", line 57, in **init**
>       desired_capabilities=capabilities)
>     File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python34\site-packages\sele
>   nium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 89, in **init**
>       self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
>     File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python34\site-packages\sele
>   nium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 138, in start_session
>       'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
>     File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python34\site-packages\sele
>   nium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 195, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>     File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python34\site-packages\sele
>   nium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 170, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unexpected error launchi
>   ng Internet Explorer. Could not get document from window handle

`IE` version 11

`IeWebDriverServer` version 2.35 x64

Why this trace appeared? Maybe someone faced the same issue.. Any help will be appreciated 
**UPDATED**

Resolved. Current `IeWebDriverServer` version replaced with v2.48

Comment: Why not use `Firefox's` or `Chrome's webdriver`?

Comment: You will find a patch [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5342)

Comment: @Vaulstein, Yes, it works with Firefox and Chrome, but the target browser for web application is an `IE`.
Thanks for link, but this patch is for x32 bit driver. Driver info updated in question,

Answer (score 0):

Check the following:

1. You are using the same security settings, for all the zones.
2. You are using the correct driver. Use the 32 bit when in doubt.
3. Make sure [your registry settings are correct](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration).
4. Zoom level is 100%.

Source: I am the creator of [Germanium](https://github.com/germaniumhq/germanium), an opensource testing API, and I support IE :)